# Express API inside Kubernetes for react and react-native apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, kubernetes

I am learning Kubernetes. I have Apollo-express GraphQL API, React frontend and React Native app. How do I connect (or) what service type should I use if I want GraphQL API to be able to connect with both frontend and mobile apps?

I got a route `/hi` that replies `Hi!` to check if it's up:

```
app.get('/hi', function (_req, res) {
  res.send('Hi!')
})
```

Here's my attempt for `api.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server-api
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 5
      containers:
        - name: server-api
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          image: my/server-api:latest
          ports:
            - name: gql
              containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: "development"
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: "redis-cache"
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: "6379"
            - name: POSTGRES_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-url
                  key: POSTGRES_URL
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-api
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: server-api
  ports:
  - name: gql
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: server-api-external
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: server-api
              servicePort: 8081
```

Minikube IP is `192.168.99.100`. But it shows `Cannot GET /` at `192.168.99.100/api/hi`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ingress is incorrect.
With your ingress, when there is incoming request to `/api/hi`, ingress will match with `/api` path rule and rewrite the path to `/` acording to `rewrite-target` annotation.

To make it work you need to use the folowing ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: server-api-external
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: server-api
              servicePort: 8081
```

Now a little explaination on how this works.
Notice changes in `path` field and `rewrite-target` annotation.
With this ingress, when there is incoming request to `/api/hi`, ingress will match `/api/(.*)` path rule, and then will extract whatever matches with `(.*)` group (that would be `hi` in this case). Next, ingress will use this matched group and rewrite the path to `/$1`, so `/` + `first group match`. At the end the path that your application receives will be `/hi` and this is what you are looking for.

Refer to [Nginx Ingress Controller documantation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) for more detailed explaination of rewrite feature.

Let me know if something is not clear enough and needs more explaination.